# Implement localStorage to clock function

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, html

I have this clock below written in Javascript that runs from the local time. it's increased by 4x speed and the problem here is that on page reload it fallbacks to localtime and starts increasing in speed again. I got help with this  localStorage function that im unsure of how to implement in the current code. Havent worked with localStorage at all before. This should make so that on page reload it continue on where it was so it doesn't fallback on the localtime.

```
    let clock = new Clock(Date.now(), 4).start();
//add the hook
clock.onStateChange = function(){
  //will be called whenever you change the state of this clock. things like changing the speed or paused state, or when you set the value.
  localStorage.setItem("clock", JSON.stringify(this));
}
//check wether there is a stored state for this "clock"
if(localStorage.hasItem("clock")){
  //simply overwrite the state of the clock.
  Object.assign(clock, JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("clock")))
}else{
  //if there's no current state stored, force storing the current state
  clock.onStateChange();
}
```

```js
 /*
a (pausable) linear equation over real time

value = _speed * Date.now() + _offset;  //+ pausing logic

so basically a clock, a stopwatch, a countdown, a gauge, ...

since it is only a linear equation over time, it is independant of any interval.
It computes the value (using Date.now()) whenever you ask for it. Wether this is ever frame or every hour.
*/
class Clock {
constructor(value=Date.now(), speed=1){
//state; changes only when YOU set one of the properties (value, paused or speed)
this._offset = +value || 0;
this._speed = +speed || 0;
this._paused = true;

//preparing a simple hook to get notified after the state has been updated (maybe to store the new state in the localStorage)
this.onStateChange = undefined;
}

get value(){
return this._paused? this._offset: this._speed*Date.now() + this._offset
}
set value(arg){
let value = +arg || 0;
let offset = this._paused? value: value - this._speed * Date.now();

if(this._offset !== offset){
this._offset = offset;
if(typeof this.onStateChange === "function")
this.onStateChange(this);
}
}

get speed(){
return this._speed
}
set speed(arg){
let speed = +arg || 0;
if(this._speed !== speed){
if(!this._paused)
this._offset += Date.now() * (this._speed - speed);
this._speed = speed;
if(typeof this.onStateChange === "function")
this.onStateChange(this);
}
}

get paused(){
return this._paused
}
set paused(arg){
let pause = !!arg;
if(this._paused !== pause){
this._offset += (pause? 1: -1) * this._speed * Date.now();
this._paused = pause;
if(typeof this.onStateChange === "function")
this.onStateChange(this);
}
}

time(){
let value = this.value,v = Math.abs(value);
return {
value,
//sign: value < 0? "-": "",
seconds: Math.floor(v/1e3)%60,
minutes: Math.floor(v/6e4)%60,
hours: Math.floor(v/36e5)%24,
days: Math.floor(v/864e5)
}
}

valueOf(){
return this.value;
}

start(){
this.paused = false;
return this;
}
stop(){
this.paused = true;
return this;
}
}

function lz(v){ //leading zero
return String(v).padStart(2, 0);
}

function update(){
let {hours, minutes, seconds} = clock.time();
let node = document.getElementById('clock');

node.textContent = [hours, minutes, seconds].map(lz).join(":");

requestAnimationFrame(update);
//setTimeout(update, 250);
}

let clock = new Clock(Date.now(), 4).start();
update();
```

```html
<h1 id="clock"></h1>
```

Comment: Im not sure `hasItem()` is a thing... can you try changing that if statement to `.getItem("clock")`?

Comment: @DelightedD0D It worked perfectly thank you!

Comment: [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) is an object, not a function. However, localStorage does have several functions (getItem, setItem, removeItem, etc...) that can be called on it. the variable `localStorage` should be available be default in most modern browsers so you can just use it like you are now. The issue is almost certainly the use of `hasItem` which is not in the default spec.

Comment: @DelightedD0D Thank you for explaining i now understand! I changed what you commented and it works perfect now.

Comment: I don’t think you can json encode the whole clock object it’s full of functions that won’t get restored.  can you not save the current time to local storage and build a new clock object from that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed `hasItem() to .getItem("clock")`   Thanks to DelightedD0D.

Comment: Glad you got it fixed. Probly best to just delete this question. Basically a typo ;)